# Compiler can't find ZLIB even though it is present

Tags: cmake, clang, clion, zlib

I have the following settings in CLion 2020.1:

[image]

I have the following lines in my `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
set(ZLIB_LIBRARY "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GnuWin32")
set(ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GnuWin32\\include")
find_package(ZLIB REQUIRED)
find_package (ZLIB)
if (ZLIB_FOUND)
  include_directories(${ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif (ZLIB_FOUND)
```

And, the compiler generates the following error:

```
C:\Users\pc\CLionProjects\myproject\src\utils/io_utils.hh(8,10): fatal error: 'zlib.h' file not found
#include <zlib.h>
         ^~~~~~~~
11 warnings and 1 error generated.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\PROGRA~1\LLVM\bin\clang-cl.exe' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

**How can I correct this?**

Comment: Calling `find_package (ZLIB)` after `find_package (ZLIB REQUIRED)` has no sense. Checking `XXX_FOUND` variable when call `find_package` with `REQUIRED` keyword has no sense too. Module [FindZLIB](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindZLIB.html) (which is used by `find_package(ZLIB)`) sets `ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS` variable, not the `ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR` one. Inside `CMakeLists.txt` all paths should have `/` as a path separator. And `ZLIB_LIBRARY` should point to the library (**file**), not a **directory**.

Comment: And according to https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindZLIB.html the library found is returned in the `ZLIB_LIBRARIES` variable not `ZLIB_LIBRARY`.

Answer (score 1):

You only need the following line:

```
find_package(ZLIB REQUIRED)

# To use zlib:
add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE ZLIB::ZLIB)
```

Then, at the command line, pass `"-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32"` as an argument to the CMake configure step. `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` may also be set as an environment variable and is formatted like your system's `PATH` env-var (so `;` separators on Windows and `:` elsewhere).

The variable `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` is consulted for a list of sysroots by the `find_*` commands. The directories in this variable should contain subdirectories like `include`, `lib`, `bin`, etc. Read more about the CMake search procedure here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#search-procedure

---

So you can see exactly what I did from the x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019:

```
D:\>dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32"
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is B854-7CB4

 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32

05/26/2021  11:40 AM    <DIR>          .
05/26/2021  11:40 AM    <DIR>          ..
05/26/2021  11:40 AM    <DIR>          bin
05/26/2021  11:40 AM    <DIR>          contrib
05/26/2021  11:40 AM    <DIR>          doc
05/26/2021  11:40 AM    <DIR>          include
05/26/2021  11:40 AM    <DIR>          lib
05/26/2021  11:40 AM    <DIR>          man
05/26/2021  11:40 AM    <DIR>          manifest
05/26/2021  11:40 AM    <DIR>          uninstall
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
              10 Dir(s)  204,769,185,792 bytes free

D:\>dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\lib"
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is B854-7CB4

 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\lib

05/26/2021  11:40 AM    <DIR>          .
05/26/2021  11:40 AM    <DIR>          ..
07/20/2005  08:52 AM            77,534 libz.a
07/20/2005  08:50 AM            43,738 libz.dll.a
07/20/2005  08:50 AM             6,656 zlib-bcc.lib
07/20/2005  08:46 AM             1,868 zlib.def
07/20/2005  08:50 AM            14,778 zlib.lib
               5 File(s)        144,574 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  204,769,185,792 bytes free

D:\>mkdir test

D:\>cd test

D:\test>notepad CMakeLists.txt

D:\test>type CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(test)

find_package(ZLIB REQUIRED)

D:\test>cmake -S . -B build "-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32"
-- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 10.0.19042.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.28.29915.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.28.29915.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29910/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29910/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found ZLIB: C:/Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32/lib/zlib.lib (found version "1.2.3")
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/test/build
```

It absolutely does find ZLIB like this.

Comment: The subsequent `make` call would be where the zlib.h include would fail. (Despite a successful cmake run)

Comment: @Alex - the subsequent call to _msbuild_ succeeds for me.